# breaking many long numbered equations

Tags: equations, numbering, line-breaking, amsmath, breqn

I am having trouble with listing a couple of  hundreds of long equations. Most of them need to be broken. The equations should be numbered. I tried many things such as `eqnarray` in combination with `multline` and as well I tried `dmath`. Here is what I have;

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{dgroup}
\begin{dmath}
\frac{dCitrate_{00000}}{dt} = ((Acetate_{00} * (J_{TCA} * (1 - P_{dil})) + DilutingPool_{00} * (J_{TCA} * P_{dil}))/(J_{TCA} *     (1 - P_{dil}) + J_{TCA} * P_{dil}) * (Oxaloacetate_{0000} + Oxaloacetate_{0001}) * J_{TCA} - J_{TCA} *     Citrate_{00000})/[Citrate]  
\end{dmath}
\begin{dmath}
\frac{dCitrate_{00001}}{dt} = ((Acetate_{00} * (J_{TCA} * (1 - P_{dil})) + DilutingPool_{00} * (J_{TCA} * P_{dil}))/(J_{TCA} *     (1 - P_{dil}) + J_{TCA} * P_{dil}) * (Oxaloacetate_{1000} + Oxaloacetate_{1001}) * J_{TCA} - J_{TCA} *     Citrate_{00001})/[Citrate] 
\end{dmath}
\begin{dmath}
\frac{dAcetylCoa_{01}}{dt} = 0 
\end{dmath}
\end{dgroup}


\end{document}
```

My first question is : Do I have to have `\begin{dmath} ... \end{dmath}` for each single equation? Also, the numbering does not look good:

[image]

Further, I would like to have the numbers in front of the equations and a numbering as 1,2,3... instead of 1a, 1b, 1c...

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks suspiciously like chemistry to me so you may find one of the chemistry packages such as `mchem` helps. The math italic font is unsuitable for multi-letter identifiers as it is explicitly designed so that runs of letters do *not* look as if they are forming a word but rather look like an implied product of one-letter identifiers. I have used `\mathrm` below, although other choices are possible.

For best results you should probably use `aligned` and break  "by hand" inserting `\\` where necessary, however if you want an automated workflow that at least keeps things on the page, then a simple scheme using inline math linebreaking can be used as shown below.

Two versions one requiring you to add an alignment point `&`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{cmath}
{\baselineskip=1.5\baselineskip \begin{center}$\displaystyle\refstepcounter{equation}}
{\hspace{\@flushglue}\mbox{(\theequation)}\hspace{-\@flushglue}$\end{center}}


\newenvironment{cmathb}
{\[%
\halign\bgroup%
\global\setbox\@ne\hbox{$\displaystyle##{}$}%
\refstepcounter{equation}\global\setbox\thr@@\hbox{(\theequation)}%
\hfill\box\@ne&%
\vtop{\baselineskip=1.5\baselineskip \parindent\z@\rightskip\fill\parfillskip\z@
  \hsize\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\@ne-\wd\thr@@\relax
   $\displaystyle{}##$\hfill\rlap{\box\thr@@}\hskip-\fill\hbox{}}\cr}%
{\crcr\egroup\]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{cmath}
\frac{\mathrm{dCitrate}_{00000}}{\mathrm{dt}} = ((\mathrm{Acetate}_{00} * (J_{\mathrm{TCA}} * (1 - P_{\mathrm{dil}})) + \mathrm{DilutingPool}_{00} * (J_{\mathrm{TCA}} * P_{\mathrm{dil}}))/(J_{\mathrm{TCA}} *     (1 - P_{\mathrm{dil}}) + J_{\mathrm{TCA}} * P_{\mathrm{dil}}) * (\mathrm{Oxaloacetate}_{0000} + \mathrm{Oxaloacetate}_{0001}) * J_{\mathrm{TCA}} - J_{\mathrm{TCA}} *     \mathrm{Citrate}_{00000})/[\mathrm{Citrate}]
\end{cmath}
\begin{cmath}
\frac{\mathrm{dCitrate}_{00001}}{\mathrm{dt}} = ((\mathrm{Acetate}_{00} * (J_{\mathrm{TCA}} * (1 - P_{\mathrm{dil}})) + \mathrm{DilutingPool}_{00} * (J_{\mathrm{TCA}} * P_{\mathrm{dil}}))/(J_{\mathrm{TCA}} *     (1 - P_{\mathrm{dil}}) + J_{\mathrm{TCA}} * P_{\mathrm{dil}}) * (\mathrm{Oxaloacetate}_{1000} + \mathrm{Oxaloacetate}_{1001}) * J_{\mathrm{TCA}} - J_{\mathrm{TCA}} *     \mathrm{Citrate}_{00001})/[\mathrm{Citrate}]
\end{cmath}
\begin{cmath}
\frac{\mathrm{dAcetylCoa}_{01}}{\mathrm{dt}} = 0 
\end{cmath}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\begin{cmathb}
\frac{d\mathrm{Citrate}_{00000}}{dt} &= ((\mathrm{Acetate}_{00} * (J_{\mathrm{TCA}} * (1 - P_{\mathrm{dil}})) + \mathrm{DilutingPool}_{00} * (J_{\mathrm{TCA}} * P_{\mathrm{dil}}))/(J_{\mathrm{TCA}} *     (1 - P_{\mathrm{dil}}) + J_{\mathrm{TCA}} * P_{\mathrm{dil}}) * (\mathrm{Oxaloacetate}_{0000} + \mathrm{Oxaloacetate}_{0001}) * J_{\mathrm{TCA}} - J_{\mathrm{TCA}} *     \mathrm{Citrate}_{00000})/[\mathrm{Citrate}]
\end{cmathb}
\begin{cmathb}
\frac{d\mathrm{Citrate}_{00001}}{dt} &= ((\mathrm{Acetate}_{00} * (J_{\mathrm{TCA}} * (1 - P_{\mathrm{dil}})) + \mathrm{DilutingPool}_{00} * (J_{\mathrm{TCA}} * P_{\mathrm{dil}}))/(J_{\mathrm{TCA}} *     (1 - P_{\mathrm{dil}}) + J_{\mathrm{TCA}} * P_{\mathrm{dil}}) * (\mathrm{Oxaloacetate}_{1000} + \mathrm{Oxaloacetate}_{1001}) * J_{\mathrm{TCA}} - J_{\mathrm{TCA}} *     \mathrm{Citrate}_{00001})/[\mathrm{Citrate}]
\end{cmathb}
\begin{cmathb}
\frac{d\mathrm{AcetylCoa}_{01}}{dt} &= 0 
\end{cmathb}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick answer, I especially like the look using `\mathrm`! Is there a way to align the equations at the "=" sign in the new `cmath` environment? Also, it would be nice if the next line after the linebreak would start after the "="..

Comment: @user1981275 You could potentially wrap it all into an `align` environment (ditching the `cmath` environments) and prefixing `&` to each `=` to align there.

Comment: @SeanAllred but then you lose the automatic line breaking unless I misunderstand what you mean?

Comment: @user1981275 you could, perhaps although it depends how far it is worth going. As I said in the answer if you really need to fine-tune the alignments then using an equation environment containing an aligned will give you full control, but you have to add the `\\ ` to specify break points.

Comment: Since I have a few hundreds of equations, I would rather prefer automated linebreaking.

Comment: If I use `\landscape`, the alignment is not too bad.

Comment: @David I'm the one who misunderstood. Whoops :P

Comment: @user1981275 alignment version added

Comment: @David Carlisle: With the alignment version, my document looks very good. Many thanks for your kind help!